# Google Finance API for getting quote has stopped working today. Is there an alternate to get quote every minute?

Tags: yahoo-finance, google-finance, google-finance-api

Below URL has stopped working from today. Any alternate ?
[Get Quote from Google Finance](https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NSE:INFY)

Comment: Saw same issue. You're the first mention i find in last 8 hours. Hopefully someone knows why.

Comment: What market are you using ?

Comment: I encountered the same issue. Waiting for solution as well.

Comment: Just seeing the same thing for both NASDAQ and ASX. Doesn't seem to work, but URLs in the `~/historical` namespace still work to get historical EOD data. e.g. `https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NASDAQ:GOOG&startdate=%271%20Sep,%202017%27` but isn't so useful programmatically...

Comment: https://finance.google.com/finance?output=json&q=TICKER_SYMBOL 
   =>  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080632/http-error-404-from-googlefinance-in-python-2-7/46081537#46081537

Comment: There are no closing prices for Sep 6 or 7 either: https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NASDAQ:MSFT

Answer (score -1):

I was using it for a long time, it looks like google has stopped it. It was very useful. The best part was you could download live prices for multiple scrips in one request.

Alternatives for **Indian Markets**:

- [Intraday one minute ohlcv data](https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=NIFTY&i=60&p=1d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v)
- [Zerodha API](https://kite.trade/docs/connect/v1/)
- [Upstox API](https://upstox.com/developer/api/v1/docs)

Comment: Thx.. Have you used Zerodha(Kite ) API ? Do you get real time quotes like google finance api ?  And  is there a limit how many times you can call the API. For me, I need to call API for 100+ stocks every minute...

Comment: I have not used it, I am currently evaluating both Zerodha & Upstox api. Both of them have limitations on number of requests in a certain time interval.

Comment: Thanks Pritesh... if you find Zerodha/Upstox good enough for every minutes quotes please let me know. I am also still  exploring ways to get quotes for multiple stocks in one call, every minute...